# PowerShell find firewall rule by displayname, port, direction and protocol

Tags: powershell, port, protocols, firewall, direction

Get-NetFirewallRule only gets you the displayname.

Get-NetFirewallPortFilter only gets you the protocol and port.

What about direction?

How to combine them together?

Get-NetFireallrule -displayname "d1"

Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where-Object {$*.LocalPort -eq 443 -and $*.Protocol -eq "TCP"}

Comment: Use following to get more properties.  You can replace * with just ones you need : Get-NetFirewallRule | Select-Object -Property *

Comment: It seems like Get-NetFirewallrule and Get-NetFirewallPortFilter are returning 2 different object.  How to combine the two?  I tried both of these but they don't work:
*
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "d1" | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -protocol tcp
*
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -protocol tcp | Where LocalPort -eq 443 | Get-NetFirewallrule -displayname "d1"

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe one to the other.  This is an efficient way to do it.

```
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -protocol tcp | Where LocalPort -eq 443 | 
  Get-NetFirewallrule | Where DisplayName -eq 'd1'
```

Comment: Based on above, how do you further filter out the displayname?  For example, Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -protocol tcp | Where LocalPort -eq 443 | Get-NetFirewallrule -displayname "d1" won't work.

Comment: @Confused Pipe to where or where-object like I showed.